# python regex to replace part of string

Tags: python, regex

Very simple question but I can't seem to figure it out.

The following code:

```
import re
addr = '800 W NORTH AVE'
re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z]+)', 'W North A', addr)
```

It gives me as a result **800 W North A W North A W North A** instead of **800 W North A**

I don't understand what am I doing wrong. Would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: There's a tool included in `c:\python27\tools\scripts\redemo.py` (season to your environment) that will visualize regex matching for you.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly your really trying to do, but for the above you could do `'800 W NORTH AVE'.title()` instead...

Answer (score 2):

You are not matching the space character. This makes every word get replaced with the replace string. You need something like this instead:

```
re.sub(r'(([a-zA-Z]+\?)+)', 'W North A', addr)
```

This matches one or more of a word followed by one or more spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Like user92454 says, you want to use a space character, which is `\s` in Python regex.

You can use the pattern `\s([A-Z\s]+)` if you know the text you want to replace is always in caps. If not, you can use `\s([A-z\s]+)` (lower case 'z').